# Issue with tracking appended to our links on triggered emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are experiencing an issue with emails we're sending in regards to the Exact Target tracking appended to our links - in some cases the tracking is preventing our links from displaying in the browser. We've done some investigation and identified a divide between our transactional emails and our marketing newsletters. For a particular example, our Twitter link is entered as https://twitter.com/feelunique in both cases, but the output differs; on our transactional emails this resolves to

//twitter.com/feelunique?utm_source=exacttarget&utm_medium=Email&utm_content=%%%3dRedirectTo(%40a)%3d%%&utm_campaign=Back+in+Stock&2/4/2015 (a blank page) whereas the marketing newsletter version resolves to

//twitter.com/feelunique?utm_source=exacttarge&utm_medium=Email&utm_term=1196256&utm_content=twitter&utm_campaign=tues_love_skin_030215_uk_ffc (which loads successfully).

It seems that the overuse of percentage symbols "%" in the first case is preventing the request from rendering. What we don't know is where the tracking is constructed and whether or not we have the ability to tweak it. The solution could be as simple as amending our transactional tracking to reflect our marketing newsletter tracking, if this is the case, could anyone advise how we would do this?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure and add `alias="STATIC TEXT HERE"` attributes to your links, otherwise, the URL specified in the `href` will get passed along in the link wrapping.

AMPScript does not get evaluated in alias tags.

Comment: @CarolinaCubria - please update your question and add the code samples. This will help those attempting to answer your question read the code better.

Comment: I have added the alias attributes in the html that we have hosted in our platform (We are using ET to pull the code and send the email) this is how our links look now: <a href="https://twitter.com/feelunique" `conversion="true" alias="twitter" target="_blank"`><img width="25" height="25" src="http://cdn1.feelunique.com/assets/img/emails/responsive/social-icons/twitte‌​r-2x.gif" alt="Follow us on Twitter" title="Follow us on Twitter" border="0"></a>  Unfortunately this is not sorting the issue, any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd contact SFMC Support and verify that your Web Analytics Connector is configured properly.  https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/