# Link breaking when sent with tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I have a link that is breaking when I send through email.  It is being sent with tracking, but I can't figure out why it's breaking.

The original link:

```
https://sportsmedicine.mayoclinic.org/performance-program/2018-mayo-clinic-mini-camp.php
```

The SFMC link:

```
https://sportsmedicine.mayoclinic.org/performance-program/2018-mayo-clinic-mini-camp.php?cm_ven=ExactTarget&cm_cat=MAYO_January_2018&cm_pla=All+Subscribers&cm_ite=https%3a%2f%2fsportsmedicine.mayoclinic.org%2fperformance-program%2f2018-mayo-clinic-mini-camp.php&cm_lm=nick.burggraf@sportngin.com&cm_ainfo=&att1=&att2=&att3=&att4=&att5=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `alias="static text here"` fixed the issue.

Here's my reference:
[Issue with tracking appended to our links on triggered emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65659/issue-with-tracking-appended-to-our-links-on-triggered-emails)